# Sublime Text 2 file associations on Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, sublimetext2

I want .js, .css, .html, etc. files to be associated with Sublime Text 2. I tried to associate the file type with the Sublime Text program, but the Open With dialog wont let me select sublime_text.exe. When I browse to the sublime_text.exe and click Open, (under Program Files, not Program Files x86; I have ST 64bit version installed) nothing happens; the browse window closes and I'm back to the stupid Open With dialog, but sublime_text.exe isn't selected and within the list available programs, and the OK button is disabled because I have nothing selected.

I'm sure there's someone out there that's more familiar with how Windows works internally and would be able to shed some light on what could be going wrong.

This all started when I installed Sublime Text 2 official release. At the time, I had Sublime Text 2 32bit beta installed, when I installed the official release, I decided to go with 64bit. After I installed the new version, I had two versions on my computer, a 32bit version and 64bit version. All my file associations were using the 32bit version, so after I uninstalled the old 32bit version (using Revo Uninstaller), all my file associations broke, and I haven't been able to fix this sense then.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1652&start=10#p7646

In case the link will die, here is content

> This actually isn't a problem with Sublime text, it's a generic quirk
>   introduced in Vista and left lingering in W7. I actually recently made
>   a blog post about this very issue, you can find it at
>   http://anders.tonfeldt.se/?p=775 but I'll detail it here since it's
>   generally considered bad form to drop an url and leave.
>
> 1. Open regedit.
> 2. Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\sublime_text.exe\shell\open\command
> 3. Verify that the path is accurate, correct it if it is not. Exit regedit.
> 4. Open task manager via ctrl+alt+del, kill explorer.exe, go to run and type explorer.exe (or skip this step and simply reboot).
> 5. Now attempt the same thing, right click a text file, open with, navigate to sublime, and it should now appear in the list of available
>      applications.
>
> Disclaimer; My post above uses another application as an example and
>   it's not guaranteed to fix your problem, but it's likely to be the
>   same as I've encountered it countless times when installing /
>   uninstalling / reinstalling an application, or just updating one, in
>   Win7/Vista.
>
> *TFeldt*

Comment: Could you please, at least, post a summary of the linked content? Otherwise your answer will become worthless the moment the link breaks.

Comment: This solved the issue. But, please do what @AlexanderKosubek said, edit and post the contents of the link that are relevant. Otherwise, I'll have to answer my own question and choose that answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, saved my bacon. (Win 10)